# Loader onLoadFinished() not called

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, loader

In preference change listener I have set it to download new data using `Loader` and then fill the `ListView`, but only the `onCreateLoader()` function is called when I change the preference, the `onLoadFinished()` callback function remains uncalled, hence my `ListView` in not updated with new data, I also happen to have a refresh button that does the same thing i.e. downloads the data gain and fills the list with new data but here the `onLoadFinished()` is called hence by updating the list.

The refresh button code

```
case R.id.menu_refresh :
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if(isConnected)
            {
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
```

The SharedPreference listener code :

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(isConnected)
    {
        //delfromold();
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();
        Log.v("Prefrences Changed",s);
    }
}
```

EDIT

Loader  Implementation

```
public class Loade extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<CustomL>>{

Context mCon;

public Loade(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mCon = context;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<CustomL> loadInBackground() {
    ArrayList<CustomL> maList = null;
    try {
        Log.v("Loader","Called");
        maList = GetList.makelist(mCon);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return maList;
}
}
```

Loader :

```
public Loader<ArrayList<CustomL>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new Loade(this);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<CustomL>> loader, ArrayList<CustomL> data) {
    Log.v("Load","Finished");
    maklst(data);
}
```

Comment: In the makelist function of the Getlist class the new data gets downloaded and saved into table i can confirm that but, its just stop there the onLoadFinished dosnt get called and maklst function that updates the list with new data is never called but when i call the same loader from refresh the onLoadFinished  is called

Answer (score 0):

You don't implement and use the `Loader` properly. It is a hard thing to do, though.

From the code above I see that you use the `forceload()` method, but you haven't implemented it in your `Loader`. If you check the source code for Loaders this method just calls the `onForceload()` event which does nothing. According to docs "Subclasses must implement this to take care of requests to `forceLoad()`. This will always be called from the process's main thread.
"

You should read [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) tutorial and start from there.

The general concept is that after you finish your `AsyncTaskLoader` implementation your fragments/activities will not contact your Loader directly. If you do that you will end up having problems with the activity/fragment lifecycle. The LoaderManager is responsible for that using these methods

1. `initLoader`
2. `restartLoader`
3. `destroyLoader`

Afterwards the `Loader` will use the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface to report any results back to the fragment/activity.